# trying to show/hide a div but something is not working

Tags: javascript, html, mootools, show

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){ 

 $('detail_block_table').addEvent('click', function(){

      if ($('detail_showDiv').getStyle('display') == 'none')
      {
          $('detail_showDiv').setStyle('display','block');
      }
      else
      {     
          $('detail_showDiv').setStyle('display','none');
      }

   });

});
```

This is the code,  it looks fine but something prevents it from working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Firstly, as @npup suggested, use toggle() method.

Secondly, the code you've posted works just fine - look: http://jsfiddle.net/oskar/my7KX/

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using mootools, why not simply do `$('detail_showDiv').toggle();` in your click handler?
Check it out in the [mootools docs](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Element/Element.Shortcuts#Element:toggle).